# Jenkins Status Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, dashboard

What is the best approach / tool to collect Jenkins job status running on multiple instances and display the status in a realtime dashboard?

Lets say I have 5 jenkins instances with 4 jobs each. I would like to keep polling all jobs and display their status in realtime dashboard.

I would like details on which open source dashboard to use, how to fetch job status and how to update the dashboard with fetched job status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:
Jenkins provide a REST API, you can build your own application (web page for example) which will poll each instances of jenkins you need.

For example to get the detail in json of the last build of a job, just GET this url:

```
<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastBuild/api/json?pretty=true
```

Hope that helps.